# Powershell error when passing a Hashtable via Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell script snippet that is calling another Powershell script using the Invoke-Expression cmdlet:

```
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $encodedCredentials")


$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
$args = @()
$args += ("-arg1", $arg1)
$args += ("-arg2", $arg2)
$args += ("-headers", $headers)
$cmd = "$ScriptPath\subScript.ps1"


Invoke-Expression "$cmd $args"
```

The list of parameters in subScript.ps1 is as follows:

```
param 
(   
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$arg1 = $(throw "arg1 is mandatory, please provide a value."), 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$arg2 = $(throw "arg2 is mandatory, please provide a value."), 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $headers = $(throw "headers is mandatory, please provide a value.")
)
```

I have verified that the second script executes when I remove the "$headers" parameter in both scripts. Once I add it again I get the following error message:

> Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert
>   the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.String" to
>   type "System.Collections.IDictionary".

I tried adding both "System.Collections.Hashtable" and "hashtable" as the type of the parameter in subScript.ps1 but that only changes the error message to:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'headers'. Cannot
>   convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type
>   "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Invoke-Expression` (it's unsafe and only works on string input) and don't (re-)use `$args` (it's an automatic variable)!

Use the hashtable for [splatting your arguments](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) instead:

```bsh
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $encodedCredentials")

$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
$params = @{
    "arg1" = $arg1
    "arg2" = $arg2
    "headers" = $headers
}
$cmd = "$ScriptPath\subScript.ps1"

# use the `&` call operator to invoke the next script
& $cmd @params
```

For more information see [the `about_Splatting` helpfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/PowerShell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7#splatting-with-hash-tables)